# Difficulties with displaying results in List Box (C#)

Tags: c#

Why when I add a number (ranging from 2 to 12) into Text Box (txtResults), why does the results not end up getting displayed into my List Box (lstTables).

Here is the look of my code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int table = 0;
        int result;

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int number = 1; number == 12; number++)
            { result = number * table;
                lstTables.Items.Add(result);
            }

        }

        private void lstTables_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void txtResults_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because of the condition in the for loop. the condition must be true for the loop to continue, and false for the loop to end. `number == 12` is always false.

Comment: chage your for loop into `for (int number = 1; number <= 12; number++)`

Comment: for loop's middle statement should return true or false in order for it to move to the next iteration. You have put 'number == 12' which is always false which means your loop will never run. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop does not have any logic, i think you need,

```
for (int number = 1; number <= 12; number++)
 { 
     result = number * table;
     lstTables.Items.Add(result);
}
```

with this also since the table value is 0, you will get 12 results with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your `For` loop is hosed.

```
  for (int number = 1; number == 12; number++)
            { result = number * table;
                lstTables.Items.Add(result);
            }
```

It's not "for startingvalue; endingvalue; iterator".  It's "for startingvalue; continue running as long as this is true value; iterator;.

```
 for (int number = 1; number < 12; number++)
                { result = number * table;
                    lstTables.Items.Add(result);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You get 12 result with `0` value because of 2 reasons :

1. `table` is set to `0` and `x * 0 = 0`,
2. You're not reassigning the same value which will be overwritten in each iteration, and thus overwritten for each items in your `lstTables`

To fix the first problem just set the `table` value to something else like `2`.
To fix the second problem just do something like this :

```
for ( int number = 1; number <= 12; ++number )
{
    int resultInLoop = number * table;
    lstTables.Items.Add(resultInLoop);
    // if you want to override `result` just uncomment below line :
    // result = resultInLoop;
}
```